# Float array as a vector of Eigen::Vector3f

Tags: c++, cuda, eigen

I am writing a Eigen on the GPU and would like to use Eigen. I have a `float*` that represent data triplets (e.g. xyz, rgb, etc) of a known size `n`. I would like to use them as an Eigen vector, but only with casting (no memory copying, as I am on the device), e.g:

```
const float* input=...
Eigen::Vector3f* inputAsFloat = ????
```

Comment: `input` points to an array of 3 floats ? or `n` floats? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: While I don't know much about Eigen, I know enough to think that you're probably not supposed to have a *pointer* to `Vector3f`. Rather you should use the *array* to initialize a `Vector3f` *object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Eigen::Map`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) to create a view on a data array:

```
float* raw_data = ....;
Eigen::Map<Vector3f> vector_map(raw_data, raw_data_size);
```

There are various options you can use:

- First template argument is the Eigen datatype you are emulating
- Second template argument is row/column major
- Third template argument is the stride option, i.e. how far apart elements and rows/columns are in memory (e.g. for extra padding per row)

Not entirely sure how well this interacts with GPU and/or CUDA.

Comment: `Eigen::Map<Vector3f>` is perfectly legit in CUDA kernels.

Answer (score 1):

My preference (though previous answers are probably correct as well):

Create a map to the original array, and then iterate through fixed-sized segments. Presumably, 'n' is a multiple of 3.

```
float* input;
int n;

Eigen::Map<VectorXf> vector_map(input,n);
   for(int i = 0; i < n/3; i++)
   {
   const Vector3f& eigen_3f = vector_map.segment<3>(3*i);
   //do things with eigen_3f
   }
```

You don't have to create a reference to 'vector_map.segment<3>(3*i)', but I think it illustrates the point.